# Address of an object returned by value from a function

Tags: c++

Considering the following minimal code:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
    MyClass() {}
};

MyClass myfunc() {
    MyClass obj;
    cout << "Address of obj in myFunc " << &obj << endl;
    return obj;
}

int main() {
    MyClass obj(myfunc());
    cout << "Address of obj in main   " << &obj << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I obtain the following output:

```
Address of obj in myFunc 0x7fff345037df
Address of obj in main   0x7fff3450380f
```

Now, just by adding a destructor in MyClass, I get the following output:

```
Address of obj in myFunc 0x7fffb6aed7ef
Address of obj in main   0x7fffb6aed7ef
```

Showing that both objects are now the same... Is this just a coincidence ?!

Also, what does exactly happen in:

```
MyClass obj(myfunc());
```

I have overloaded the copy constructor to print a message, but it never appears...

Comment: [Return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) is kicking in.

Comment: @ presius litel snoflek: Why does the compiler use RVO only after a dtor is added?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By adding a destructor (whatever it was that you actually did, you're not showing the code) the behavior changed to use **Return Value Optimization**, known as RVO.

Then a pointer to the caller's storage is passed to the function, and the function constructs the object directly in that storage, instead of e.g. copying a value in a processor register or set of registers.

The same calling convention, with a hidden result storage pointer, can also be used without RVO. Without RVO a copy or move is performed at the end of the function. The standard supports RVO optimization under certain conditions, but, while it can be reasonably expected, a compiler is not under any obligation to perform RVO.

Comment: Any ideas as to why adding a destructor would lead the compiler to suddenly realize it could use RVO? (Probably near impossible to answer since it's so tightly tied to the implementation, but still curious.)

Comment: @Lilshieste: The compiler may use fairly mechanical, non-intelligent rules for what objects can be passed by copy in registers. An object with no state, but with destructor, would be more efficient to return by doing *nothing*. Avoiding that hidden storage pointer argument. But a rule that "destructor means non-trivial object" makes sense because why would have a stateless object with destructor, in real code.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Why is that? Can you explain a bit why that would be more efficient? Isn't the destructor called whether it be a default destructor or a custom one?

Comment: @Lawrence: doing nothing is always more efficient than doing something. but yeah, if the destructor does something, then it can be better to avoid two destructor calls. if was thinking of the OP adding an empty destructor, sorry.

Comment: I tried with g++, adding a copy ctor can also cause the optimization.